# Is this an appropriate use case for a recursive mutex?

Tags: c, mutex, recursive-mutex

I've heard from various sources
([1](http://www.zaval.org/resources/library/butenhof1.html),
[2](https://books.google.com/books?id=kCTMFpEcIOwC&pg=PA434#v=onepage&q&f=false))
that one should avoid using recursive mutexes as it may be a sign of a hack or
bad design. Sometimes, however, I presume they may necessary. In light of that,
is the following an appropriate use case for a recursive mutex?

```c
// main.c
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic main.c -pthread

#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif /* _GNU_SOURCE */

#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct synchronized_counter
{
    int count;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_mutexattr_t mutexattr;
} synchronized_counter;

synchronized_counter* create_synchronized_counter()
{
    synchronized_counter* sc_ptr = malloc(sizeof(synchronized_counter));
    assert(sc_ptr != NULL);

    sc_ptr->count = 0;

    assert(pthread_mutexattr_init(&sc_ptr->mutexattr) == 0);
    assert(pthread_mutexattr_settype(&sc_ptr->mutexattr, 
        PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE) == 0);

    assert(pthread_mutex_init(&sc_ptr->mutex, &sc_ptr->mutexattr) == 0);

    return sc_ptr;
}

void synchronized_increment(synchronized_counter* sc_ptr)
{
    assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&sc_ptr->mutex) == 0);

    sc_ptr->count++;

    assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&sc_ptr->mutex) == 0);
}

int main()
{
    synchronized_counter* sc_ptr = create_synchronized_counter();

    // I need to increment this counter three times in succesion without having
    // another thread increment it in between. Therefore, I acquire a lock
    // before beginning.

    assert(pthread_mutex_lock(&sc_ptr->mutex) == 0);

    synchronized_increment(sc_ptr);
    synchronized_increment(sc_ptr);
    synchronized_increment(sc_ptr);

    assert(pthread_mutex_unlock(&sc_ptr->mutex) == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:

I wanted to ask the question with a simple example, but perhaps it came across as *too* simple. This is what I had imagined would be a more realistic scenario: I have a stack data structure that will be accessed by multiple threads. In particular, sometimes a thread will be popping n elements from the stack, but it must do so all at once (without another thread pushing or popping from the stack in between). The crux of the design issue is if I should have the client manage locking the stack themselves with a non-recursive mutex, or have the stack provide synchronized, simple methods along with a recursive mutex which the client can use to make multiple atomic transactions that are also synchronized.

Comment: If you do not use recursive capable mutex, you *MUST* ensure that your code doesn't recurse. When you dealing with your own code, this is ease to achieve but when you export libraries you don't know the code that it will call you, so providing a recursive capable function can be more generic. I can't see any other use

Comment: @geckos Well said. In methods like these, I'm having a hard time deciding whether it should be up to the client to ensure synchronized access or if it's something I should provide. In this instance, it's code that I will be using, so I think having a non-recursive mutex will do the job.

Comment: If doing API I would export two functions, one supporting recursive and another not. Recursive mutex may have more overhead than the non-recursive ones, but, If I have a problem that is better handled by recursion I would go with recursive mutex until they prove to be a problem. I also heard of a good source that _Premature optimization is the root of all evil_, if your problem is not recursive, go with non-recursive mutex :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your examples - the original `synchronized_counter` and the stack in your edit - are correct examples of using a recursive mutex, but they would be considered poor API design if you were building a data structure. I'll try to explain why.

1. **Exposing internals** - the caller is required to use the same lock that protects internal access to members of the data structure. This opens the possibility to misusing that lock for purposes other than accessing the data structure. That could lead to lock contention - or worse - deadlock.
2. **Efficiency** - it's often more efficient to implement a specialized bulk operations like `increment_by(n)` or `pop_many(n)`.

   - First, it allows the data structure to optimize the operations - perhaps the counter can just do `count += n` or the stack could remove `n` items from a linked list in one operation. [1]
   - Second, you save time by not having to lock/unlock the mutex for every operation.[2]

---

Perhaps a better example for using a recursive mutex would be as follows:

- I have a class with two methods `Foo` and `Bar`.
- The class was designed to be single-threaded.
- Sometimes `Foo` calls `Bar`.

I want to make the class thread-safe, so I add a mutex to the class and lock it inside `Foo` and `Bar`. Now I need to make sure that `Bar` can lock the mutex when called from `Foo`.

One way to solve this without a recursive mutex is to create a private `unsynchronized_bar` and have both `Foo` and `Bar` call it after locking the mutex.

This can get tricky if `Foo` is a virtual method that can be implemented by a sub-class and used to call `Bar`, or if `Foo` calls out to some other part of the program that can call back into `Bar`. However, if you have code inside critical sections (code protected by a mutex) calling into other arbitrary code, then the behaviour of the program will be hard to understand, and it is easy to cause deadlocks between different threads, even if you use a recursive mutex.

The best advice is to solve concurrency problems through good design rather than fancy synchronization primitives.

---

[1] There are some tricker patterns like "pop an item, look at it, decide if I pop another one", but those can be implemented by supplying a predicate to the bulk operation.

[2] Practically speaking locking a mutex you already own should be pretty cheap, but in your example it requires at least a call to an external library function, which cannot be inlined.

Comment: Regarding point 1, I _was_ going to ask whether having the data structure manage its own locks would provide a way to avoid exposing the internals, but point 2 conflicts with that design choice. I think I understand the trade-off now: I can either have the calling thread acquire a lock to do bulk operations, or have the data structure provide an API that allows bulk operations, but in both scenarios, only a non-recursive mutex is required. Using a recursive mutex would be overkill when confronted with this alternative design choice.

Comment: I think I'm leaning towards having the API provide bulk operations so the client doesn't have to worry about synchronization. Anyhow, thank you for the well-reasoned explanation!

Comment: @Anton, if I'm going to provide a method that does bulk pops from a stack, but I want to use the elements I'm popping, I would likely have to return some kind of list. Is this how you imagined it would be done?

Comment: @asfeynman you could return a list or pass in a function pointer to process the items one at a time as they are popped. It really depends on how you are using this data structure.

Comment: @Anton, gotcha.

Answer (score -1):

The logic that you describe is not, in fact, a recursive mutex, nor is it an appropriate case for one.

And, if you actually need to ensure that another thread won't increment your counter, I'm sorry to tell you that your logic as-written won't ensure that.

I therefore suggest that you step back from this, clear your head, and re-consider your actual use-case.  I think that confusion about recursive mutexes has led you astray.  It may well be the case that the logic which you now have in `synchronized_increment` ... in fact, the need for the entire method ... is unnecessary, and the logic which you show in `main` is all you really need, and it's just a simple variable after all.

Comment: "The logic that you describe is not, in fact, a recursive mutex." Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but isn't `create_synchronized_counter()` creating a recursive mutex? "If you actually need to ensure that another thread won't increment your counter." The goal was to have the main thread increment the counter three times in succession, without having another thread increment the counter in between. If that isn't happening as intended, can you describe a scenario where it might not work?

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, please see the edit.